What is difference between mem copy and full copy in lmbench3?
I am trying to understand the bandwidth benchmarking. I came across these routines MCP and FCP in lmbench3. I disassembled the binary and found these, both in loops that increment pointers by 32.
MCP :

ldr x2, [x0]
str x2, [x1]
These instructions were executed in a loop

FCP :

ldp q0, q1, [x0]
stp q0, q1, [x1]
These instructions were executed in a loop

Can these two behave differently ?  memory accessing and register used are different, what can I infer more from this ?
Both routines are for measuring the Bandwidth, wanted to understand the difference. Tried going through source code.

MCP copies 8 bytes at a time.  FCP copies 32 at a time (a pair of 16-byte vectors).  So MCP sucks if data is aligned and hot in cache, especially on CPUs with wide data paths for accessing L1d cache.

Thanks @PeterCordes. Yeah, like you pointed, there is difference between STR and STP (similarly with load).
I have two doubts.

how is this integrated into binary ? the offset in both routines is #32 in lmbench3. So where is the adjustment for this done in lmbench3 ?
You said when data is aligned and hot in cache, MCP underperforms.  can we say bandwidth measured in FCP will be always greater than or equal to MCP ?


Oh, so MCP touches every cache line, but only actually copies 8 bytes of every 32?  So it's testing L1 fill bandwidth from L2 or DRAM, without being limited by bandwidth between L1d and registers.  If you'd shown that in the question in the first place, I wouldn't have had to make assumptions about the pointer increments.

If you did have a memcpy function that used 8-byte at a time copying, it might be faster on some CPUs for some sizes and alignments than ldp/stp of q registers.  Especially smaller misaligned data.  But if lmbench always aligns its buffers, then yeah using wider registers would always be faster (if the 8-byte-at-a-time loop only incremented its pointer by 8, unlike lmbench's MCP which isn't a true memcpy.)

okay, my bad @PeterCordes.  For given binary ( both routines accessing data at every 32), FCP vs MCP : since MCP is not accessing data continuously (just 8byte out of 32byte), will that mean if data is cacheable FCP performance better ?

No, on most CPUs I'd expect MCP to be at least as fast since it's doing less work.  For it to be faster, a CPU would have to have some special support for full-line writes like maybe avoiding RFOs (read for ownership).  But it only writes 32 bytes at a time, not 64 (the typical cache-line size on modern CPUs)

Oh okay @PeterCordes.
if I want to measure bandwidth (copy) of a system, which one is more preferred ? Incase of ARM I have multiple options, temporal and non temporal, Q and X registers, STR/LDR and STP/LDP ? too much options...

It probably depends on the CPU what's most efficient for a full memcpy.  Maybe also on the buffer size (like too big for cache or not), and whether the destination is already hot in cache.  e.g. for a small copy with the destination hot in cache, you'd obviously want temporal stores so you can get cache hits.  For a large copy, usually non-temporal stores to avoid extra read bandwidth for RFOs on the destination (if they work like x86 movnt).  For a small copy that's cold in cache, could maybe go either way for the copy itself, but reading the copy later will be faster if it stays in cache

You could look at what glibc chooses based on size and CPU features for its memcpy.  https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/aarch64/multiarch/memcpy.c.html is the ifunc dispatcher which picks a memcpy implementation at dynamic link time (the function pointer goes into the GOT entry used by the PLT, so later calls will go directly to the version it picked.)
